# Entity framework Context.SaveChanges() not inserting data in the table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity framework 4.1, the following method I am using to insert data in the table it is not inserting data in the table.

Method:

```
    private void InsertSMSStatus(Request request)
    {
        UtilitiesEntities context = new UtilitiesEntities();
        SMSAlertLog alertLog = new SMSAlertLog();
        alertLog.Recipients = request.To;
        alertLog.Sender = From;
        alertLog.Status = Convert.ToInt32(request.ResponseString);
        context.SaveChanges();
        context.Dispose();
    }
```

The Connection string:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" /></startup><connectionStrings><add name="UtilitiesEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.SmsEntityModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.SmsEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.SmsEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=bosql1srv;initial catalog=Utilities;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings></configuration>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: You haven't inserted anything into your context. You need to do something like that: `context.AlertLogs.Add(alertLog); context.SaveChanges();` .. depending on your context of course.

Comment: oops that was a misss.... Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not adding your entity into context.

```
context.SMSAlertLogs.Add(alertLog); // name of entity set may change. It might not be SMSAlertLogs 
context.SaveChanges();
```